# C# JsonArray to string (not string array. string only)

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net, winrt-xaml

I've been searching for this one for quite a while but can't find anything. Appologies then for the title, as there is a lot on converting content to String Arrays, which is not what I need.

I need a way to convert the contents of a JsonArray to string just as is. (Similar to JToken's .ToString()). My scenario is of such a nature that I need the string of an array just as is, irrigardless of the type/s contained within. There are ways of handling weakly typed json with ValueConverters, but I spesifically do not want to use them, as I need to pass the content of a field as a string to a Javascript Function in a WebView.

I have the following json (note markers indicating where string is desired) :

```
"highlights2":[
  {
    "_id":"highlight2-2850cb68121f9d4093e67950665c45fab02cec81",
    "_rev":"9-c4345794001495104f8cbf5dd6999f3a",
    "content":{             <---- Need this as string
      "#roepman.17.0":[
        [
          233,
          249,
          "itsi-hl-gr"
        ],
        [
          298,
          317,
          "itsi-hl-bl"
        ]
      ],
      "#roepman.19.0":[
        [
          5,
          7,
          "itsi-hl-gr"
        ]
      ]
    },                  <----- Up to here
    "created":1434552587
  }, //...more like this 
],
"book":"book-930d62a2-9b7c-46a9-b092-f90469206900",
"serverTime":1435151280
```

Ideally I want to parse it into a list of the following type:

```
public class HighlightInfo2
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string _rev { get; set; }}
    public string content { get; set; }
    public long created { get; set; }
}
```

However this is not possible, as the content of "content" is of type JsonArray. So to get past not having to specify a type for "content", I use this:

```
public class HighlightInfo2
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string _rev { get; set; }}
    public Dictionary<string, List<JsonArray>> content { get; set; }
    public long created { get; set; }
}
```

But this means I still have to at some point convert the List< JsonArray > inside the dictionary to a string as I pass the content of "content" to a Javascript function in a webview later on.

Any way of converting the JsonArray to a string?

Comment: Aren't you trying to work around some other problem that exists elsewhere? Why do you need that content as string? I would say: If it was meant to be a string, it would be.

Comment: I pass the string onto a JavaScript function, this function takes the string, stores it and when needed, parses is in JS for further use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, the formatting of that string is irrelevant. It just has to be valid JSON representing the original data.

What I would suggest then is to make your `content` member in `HighlightInfo2` of type `object` and simple perform a `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(highlightInfo.content)` to get the JSON string. This is what you can then pass over to the JavaScript function.

If you need to do this often, you can combine this with [Behzad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044187/572644) and add another member to your class that stores this converted value.

Comment: Came here to say exactly this :) Shortly after Daniel Hilgarth's comment yesterday I realized I was being silly, and that I can just Serialize the json, and store it as is. I now make the content member of type JToken. Combining it with Behzad's answer, I make a contentString member, which does the conversion. Finally adding a Scriptignore attribute to the contentString field so as to not serialize it later on.

Comment: Just one question remaining then. Any reason you chose an Object type? Is using JToken better/worse? (imo having any other type than Object is usually better) - Keep in mind, the whole highlight2 object is saved in a SQLite database at the end of the day.

Comment: @nicovanvuuren: My thinking was: This member is an intermediate step that you don't actually want to use. Making it `object` communicates this - at least a little bit. From a technical point of view, using `JToken` will work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

What i suggest is to make another property like contentJson under highlightInfo2 class and put the string of jsonarray in it.

```
public class HighlightInfo2
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<JsonArray>> _content;
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string _rev { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, List<JsonArray>> content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            foreach (var item in _content)
            {
                contentJson += string.Join("\r\n", item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
     [JsonIgnore] //note, this depends on your json serializer
    public string contentJson { set; get; }
    public long created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea in general, but your concrete code won't generate valid JSON. You should be using facilities that generate valid JSON. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31045054/572644) for an example.

Comment: Yes, you are right, simply by adding the [JsonIgnore] or [ScriptIgnore] the model will be valid, right ?

Comment: No. What I mean is that the value of `contentJson` will not have the expected value. After fixing the errors in the code, mainly `JArray` instead of `JsonArray` and `contentJson += ` instead of `contentJson = `, the result of `contentJson` will only be [the array representations without the property names](http://pastebin.com/gyessQVb).

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of [Daniel's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31045054/1235034) and [Behzad's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044187/1235034), I came up with this class/type for deserialization, which works without a hitch. Thanks for the help.

```
public class HighlightInfo2
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string _rev { get; set; }
    public long created { get; set; }

    private JToken _content { get; set; }
    public JToken content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            contentString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string contentString { get; set; }

}
```